# ASP.NET ListView Paging : Invalid viewstate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

I have a ListView control as follows (for posting here I've removed the values from my ItemTemplate):

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDataSource">
  <LayoutTemplate>
     <div id="requests" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></asp:Panel>
     </div>
     <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="3">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" PreviousPageText="<--" NextPageText="-->" />
        </Fields>
     </asp:DataPager>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div ID="itemPlaceholder" class="request" runat="server">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="button" runat="server" Text='...' CommandName="..." 
                CommandArgument='...' OnClick="..."
                style="...">
        </asp:LinkButton> -  
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This ListView exists as a user control (.ascx), which I've embedded into an ASPX web page.

As I expect, when the web page loads, for a list of 9 items, I get 3 pages of 3 items.

When I click to go to the next page, the page loads the next set of items correctly... but only for a brief second. Then a strange thing happens. The page embeds a copy of itself inside the page 6 times, each one of them underneath one of the fields on the form inside the page.

If I then attempt to go to the next or previous page, an ASP.NET server error appears:

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

In the stack trace, it shows the following errors:

> FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.
>
> ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.

I was able to replicate this on both my browsers, IE8 and Chrome.

Comment: Looks that problem is in databinding. Please, provide a server code and data source code.

Answer (score 0):

you use listview event  OnPagePropertiesChanging

like this

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvCustomers" runat="server"   GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"    OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
```

in aspx.cs

```
protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender,PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    (lvCustomers.FindControl("DataPager1") as  DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
this.BindListView();
}
```

BindListView() is method for binding list view

[visit this link for example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-in-ASPNet-ListView-control-using-DataPager-without-using-DataSource-control.aspx)

i hope it's helpfull

Comment: it's work when your data binding is correct....give some code so I will give proper solution   thanks